# Unpickling a file using os.path

Tags: python, pandas, pickle, urllib

I'm getting a weird error when running the following code:

```
import os
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

data_url = 'URL FROM GOOGLE DRIVE DOWNLOAD'
file_name = 'mask.pkl'
data_dir = os.path.join('tempdata', 'test')
file_path = os.path.join(data_dir, file_name)
gdrive_file(file_path, data_url, data_dir)
x = pd.read_pickle(file_path) 
mask = x[0]
```

Where the `data_url` is a download link from Google Drive, but it's just a .pkl file, any .pkl you use to test this should throw the same error. The `gdrive_file()` function is defined as follows:

```
def gdrive_file(file_path, data_url, data_dir):
    if file_path is True:
        pass
    if not os.path.isfile(file_path):
        print('Fetching example data file')
        os.makedirs(data_dir, exist_ok=True)
        return urllib.request.urlretrieve(data_url, file_path)
```

Everything works great up to the point where I use pandas to read the .pkl file. I get the following error:

```
    In [11]: pd.read_pickle(file_path)
    #---------------------------------------------
    UnpicklingError                           
    Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-11-f996be11e8eb> in <module>
    ----> 1 pd.read_pickle(file_path)
    ~/anaconda3/envs/reborn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py in read_pickle(filepath_or_buffer, compression)
    180                 # We want to silence any warnings about, e.g. moved modules.
    181                 warnings.simplefilter("ignore", Warning)
--> 182                 return pickle.load(f)
    183         except excs_to_catch:
    184             # e.g.
UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '<'.
```

I've used this same code to open other data types, it's just having an issue with opening .pkl file using `pd.read_pickle(file_path)` and I'm not sure why.

Comment: By the way, should consider using pathlib instead of os.path.

Comment: @AMC Why do you say that?

Comment: Pathlib is quite nice. See, for example https://treyhunner.com/2018/12/why-you-should-be-using-pathlib/.